# Screen being rendered twice only after the initial click

Tags: react-native

So basically I need to reach this DetailScreen and when I click on the button to navigate to it, I pass in an ID to find the correct object from the state.

On the first click, it is rendered once and from the console.log it outputs the result once.

But after I navigate back to the HomePage using the headerLeft, and then try to click on any tile (not just the one I clicked on earlier) they all render twice and output twice the logs from DetailScreen.

Only the first click renders once and I get one set of logs from DetailScreen. After that DetailScreen outputs logs twice as it is rendering twice.

Here is a snippet after first click.
[FirstClick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTn9P.png)

Here is a snippet after any number of clicks after
[SameTile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvK9Z.png)
[DifferentTile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ2Dj.png)

### Here is my Code below

#### App.js

```
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/HomeScreen";
import DetailScreen from "./src/screens/DetailScreen";

import { Ionicons, Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { Provider } from './src/context/TileContext';
 
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
 
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerTitle: "MyApp" }}>
          <Drawer.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={HomeScreen}
          />
          
          <Drawer.Group screenOptions={{ drawerItemStyle: { display: 'none' } }}>
            <Drawer.Screen
              name="Detail"
              component={DetailScreen}
              options={({navigation: {navigate} }) => ({
                headerLeft: () => (
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('Home')}>
                    <Ionicons name='arrow-back-outline' size={40} style={{marginLeft: 15, marginBottom: 5}} />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                )
              })}
            />
          </Drawer.Group>
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
      fontSize: 30,
      marginLeft: 15
  }
});
```

#### DetailScreen.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Context } from '../context/TileContext';

const DetailScreen = ({ route }) => {
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();
    const { state } = useContext(Context);

    if(!isFocused){
        return;
    }

    console.log('Detail Screen: ' + route.params.id);
    
    const tile = state.find((tile) => tile.id === route.params.id);
    
    return (
        <View>
            <View styles={styles.containerStyle}>
                <Text>Detail Screen</Text>
                <Text>{tile.title}</Text>
                <Text>{tile.notes}</Text>
                <Text>All Images Shown Below</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    containerStyle: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
    }
})

export default DetailScreen;
```

### Adding TileComponent just in case it is needed.

#### TileComponent.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { Context } from '../context/TileContext'
import { Feather, FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const TileComponent = ({ detail }) => {
    const { deleteTile } = useContext(Context);
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    console.log('TileComponent')

    return (
        <View style={styles.tileStyle}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Detail', { id: detail.id })}>
                <View style={styles.childContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>{detail.title}</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.childContainer2}>
                    <Text style={styles.notesStyle}>{detail.notes}</Text>

                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.counterStyle} >
                            <FontAwesome style={styles.buttonStyle} name='minus-square' />
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <Text style={{alignSelf: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Count: 0</Text>

                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.counterStyle}>
                            <Feather style={styles.buttonStyle} name='plus-square' />
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.iconContainer} onPress={() => deleteTile(detail.id)}>
                            <Feather style={styles.icon} name='trash' />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
};

export default TileComponent;
```

I tried multiple things and added a lot of logging to try and figure out why it's being rendered twice but couldn't figure it out. I do know that when a state changes, it renders again but there is no state change here so I am a bit confused.

Comment: `useContext` can also re-render your component.

What I use to debug re-rendering is something like `useEffect(() => { console.log('DetailScreen re-render because "state" changed', state); }, [state]);` which will `console.log` every time `DetailScreen` is re-rendered because `state` has changed. 

(side note - use separate useEffect for each variable that can re-render your component). 

Specifically for `DetailScreen` I would also add `useEffect(() => { console.log('DetailScreen re-render because "isFocused" changed', isFocused); }, [isFocused]);`